# I tried to distinguish about MOSFET statement,,,

Tags: mosfet

About during studying MOSFET, I was confused about this.
I hope to distinguish about when is triode, cut off, and Active,

umm I think if V0= 5V, then MOSFET is open state, so i guess
cut off states range is  when Vi = V_GS < 0.8V
(0.8 = Vth) that is right...?

I dont know How to distinguish triode and active range...
when  V0= 0V then triode,  when V0 =2.5V then active right? and I hope to get advice about how know Vi range.

```
V0 = 0V  => triode?? and what range is Vi... 

V0 = 5V  => cut off?? and range is Vi<0.8V..?

V0 = 2.5V => active ?? and what range is Vi...
```

I started semester from March 5th Fri. and learning about MOSFET in this week
so I need to know concept exactly..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMPctZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You have your output on the wrong node. You have your 5 volt supply inverted.

Comment: @Andyaka Ohh really!! Thank you to let know me. Really. umm Can you give me advice about How to distinguish well and know range well...? cuz I try to find concept but All is not about this...

Comment: See @Hearth's answer for how to draw the schematic. Note that having the ground pointing towards the ground (rather than the sky) helps you keep everything positive side up.

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the datasheet.

[image: A standard Id/Vds graph, with traces for a variety of different Vgs conditions. A red curve is drawn across it, separating it into two halves labelled "Triode" and "Linear"]

(*[image source](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91019/91019.pdf)*)

Here, I've drawn a line roughly separating the triode and linear regions. As you can see, the mode depends both on Vds *and* Vgs, so there's no way to tell from only one of these which mode it's in.

However, since you know that the drain current is 100 μA, knowing Vds alone is sufficient to know what mode it's in. At least, it would be if the datasheet graph went down that low; since it doesn't, the most you can do is make an educated guess. This isn't a FET designed for use at such low drain currents.

---

Note: Here, I'm assuming you meant the circuit you probably meant, which I've drawn below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0lX8L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you actually meant what you drew, the answer would be very different--In the circuit you drew, Vo is always exactly -5 V.

Comment: Really thank you to reply me..!!! but...I am newbie in here so I dont know how to erase model name..so put that... Actually Model name is nothing.. sorry .. but Really thank you!!